# oracle REGEXP_SUBSTR

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-substr

I've this string: GS24;;5289;TREG;248;LGS242604UG3AS7RWA;;[{"376108228000002801";;1}]

and I just want this number: LGS242604

What is the correct `REGEXP_SUBSTR` expression?

thx for helping!

Comment: What's the logic to find this number? 6th field based on semicolon as delimiter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This allows for NULL elements and strips the double-quotes:

```
SQL> Select
   replace(REGEXP_SUBSTR('"TS00;GS27;2;SXOR;"0000000001";"176108339523074094";8;8;[99];[(LAHE:227)"', '(.*?)(;|$)', 1, 6, NULL, 1), '"') AS field6
   FROM    dual;

FIELD6
------------------
176108339523074094

SQL>
```